# Gridelements and fluid styled content

Tags: typo3, fluid-styled-content

I use Gridelements with a custom `FLUIDTEMPLATE`

Inside my `FLUIDTEMPLATE` I want to get the images/file references of my textmedia content elements (`fluid_styled_content`).

I also tried to use the Dataprocessing without success.

Comment: Can you post your approach with DataProcessor? Which TYPO3 version are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this for News:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.relatedFiles}">
    <ul>
        <f:for each="{newsItem.relatedFiles}" as="relatedFile">
            <li>
                {relatedFile.title}
                {relatedFile.file}
            </li>
        </f:for>
    </ul>
</f:if>
```